# WPF Binding to a RadioButton GroupName

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, radio-button

I have a dynamic `ListView` using a `DataTemplate` as follows:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#ccc">
        <RadioButton GroupName="MyRadioButtonGroup">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,5" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=CheckoutGrid}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Test1, StringFormat='{}{0} - '}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Test2, StringFormat='{} test {0} - '}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Test, StringFormat='{} test {0}'}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </RadioButton>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I would like to have a button disabled until one of the RadioButton `IsChecked`:

```
<RadioButton Padding="15,10" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<RadioButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleToggleButton4}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyRadioButtonGroup, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</RadioButton.Style>
<TextBlock FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="14" Margin="0">NEXT</TextBlock>
</RadioButton>
```

So the problem is I do not know how to properly bind to the `RadioButton GroupName="MyRadioButtonGroup"`. You will see in the `DataTrigger` above I am trying `Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyRadioButtonGroup, Path=IsChecked}" Value="False"`, but that is not working for me since obviously it is a `GroupName` and not an `x:Name`.

Any suggestions on how to approach this properly? I would rather want to handle this on the front-end if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your radio button to a command and then use the isChecked as a parameter. Then bind to a boolean value based off that. I think this may be more of a workaround though.

```
<RadioButton
        Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}"
        GroupName="radio" />
<RadioButton
        Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsChecked}"
        GroupName="radio" />
```

Then in code behind or VM, it would require implementing the ICommand Interface and INotifyPropertyChanged

```
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked;}
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnMyCommand(object obj)
    {
        if(obj is bool)
        {
            IsChecked = (bool)obj;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A group has no `IsChecked` property that you can bind to.

If you don't have a source property that keeps track of whether there is at least one checked `RadioButton` and "want to handle this on the front-end" - which I guess means in the view - you could write some code that simply sets the `Tag` property of the `ListView` to `true`/`false` depending on whether there is a `RadioButton` selected. It is a one-liner:

```
private void ListView_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => lv.Tag = true;
```

---

```
<ListView x:Name="lv" ToggleButton.Checked="ListView_Checked">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        ...
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<RadioButton Padding="15,10" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <RadioButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="RadioButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource styleToggleButton4}">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lv, Path=Tag}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Style>
    <TextBlock FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="14" Margin="0">NEXT</TextBlock>
</RadioButton>
```